# C++11 Threads - start infinite worker thread from inside a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, infinite

i wanna provide a class, that holds a buffer while reading in some data (udp packets or from a file). Everything is fine if i start my thread from the main, but in this case i want to avoid, that the user has to set up a new thread for himself.

so here is my code as simple as i could make it:

```
class DataCollector
{
    void startCollect()
    {
        std::thread t1(readSource);
    }

    bool readSource()
    {
        while(1)
        {
            // read some data for storage
        }
    }   
}

int main()
{
    DataCollector myDataCollector;
    myDataCollector.startCollect();

    while(1)
    {
        // do some other work, for example interpret the data
    }

    return 0;
}
```

now i need your help. How can i call this thread inside startCollect?

edit1:
here is my example of how it works NOW!

```
// ringbuffertest.cpp : Definiert den Einstiegspunkt für die Konsolenanwendung.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>

class DataCollector
{
private:
    //std::thread collecterThread;

public:
    DataCollector(){}

    void startCollect()
    {       
        readSource();
    }

    bool readSource()
    {
        while (1)
        {
            printf("Hello from readSource!\n");
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        return false;
    }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DataCollector myDataCollector;

    std::thread t1(&DataCollector::startCollect, std::ref(myDataCollector));

    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

but as i said i would like to hide the thread call inside my startCollect function.

Comment: Shouldn't the thread be a property of DataCollector? Then you could instantiate it in the constructor and start it in startCollect.

Comment: You will need to have a buffer (or two) and use condition_variable to notify each thread that one has provided some data.

Comment: yeh i know about my buffers. i just threw everything out from my programm to make it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before destroying an active `thread` object, it must either be *joined* (waiting for the thread to finish, then cleaning up its resources) or *detached* (left to run and clean itself up when finished).

So you could either make the thread a member variable, so that it can be joined later:

```
void startCollect()
{
    this->thread = std::thread(&DataCollector::readSource, this);
}

void waitForCollectToFinish()
{
    this->thread.join();
}
```

or you could detach it, if you don't need the ability to wait for it to finish, and have some other way of signalling that data is available:

```
void startCollect()
{
    std::thread([this]{readSource();}).detach();
}
```

You might also look at higher-level concurrency facilities, such as `std::async` and `std::future`. These might be more convenient than dealing with threads directly.

Comment: You can see this method in action on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87b6ee616f912cd9).

Comment: this->thread = std::thread(readSource, this); gets me compiler errors. i will edit a working example(where i start the thread from main).

Comment: @user3783662: You're right, it should be `&DataCollection::readSource`. Or, perhaps more readable, the lambda `[this]{readSource();}`.